# How to save buffer from command?

Tags: command

I'm trying to get `:W` to also save like `:w` (I often mistype). I tried something like this:
`command! W execute "norm! w"`, but that doesn't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`norm!` (short for `normal!`) executes commands in normal mode. A "command" in normal mode is a key you use to do something; for example `w` to go to the next word, `dd` to delete the line, and many more.

`command` expects ex commands, or CLI commands. That is, what you type after pressing `:`.

It's a bit confusing both are called "commands".

So to get your command, you can do:

```
command W w
```

Which will work fine for typo-ing `:W` to `:w`, but if you want `:W file` to work you need to also pass any arguments:

```
command -nargs=* -bang -complete=file W w<bang> <args>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did have me confused!

Comment: I'd suggest to add the `<bang>` attribute as well: `command -nargs=* -bang -complete=file W w<bang> <args>`

Comment: Ah yeah, cheers @ChristianBrabandt